# Remove Docker limit-cpu, limit-memory, reserve cpu and memory

Tags: docker, limit, docker-swarm

I am currently using a Docker Swarm with limit-cpu, limit-memory and reserve cpu and memory.

After done my testing I would like to remove these configurations. I couldn't find any article for how to remove these.

Is there anyway to remove these setting by update without delete and recreate the docker service?

Docker version

> ```
> Client:
>  Version:           18.06.1-ce
>  API version:       1.38
>  Go version:        go1.10.3
>  Git commit:        e68fc7a215d7133c34aa18e3b72b4a21fd0c6136
>  Built:             Tue Oct  2 18:06:45 2018
>  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
>  Experimental:      false
>
> Server:
>   Engine:
>   Version:          18.06.1-ce
>   API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
>   Go version:       go1.10.3
>   Git commit:       e68fc7a/18.06.1-ce
>   Built:            Tue Oct  2 18:08:26 2018
>   OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
>   Experimental:     false
> ```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `docker service update` full documentation can be found here -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/

To update or remove the cpu and memory limits you could run this command

```
docker service update --limit-cpu 0 --limit-memory 0 --reserve-cpu 0 --reserve-memory 0 service_name
```